# Start to build a robot

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, robotics

I would like to start with a very simple robot, which should be based on an arduino uno.
I already have an uno and made the decision fpr my robot chassie:
https://www.roboter-bausatz.de/en/diy-electronics/kits/robotic-kits/97/2wd-motor-smart-car-chassis-fuer-roboter-mit-getriebemotor-und-batteriebox

Additionally I want to by an ultrasonic distance sensor and a infrared sensor.
What else do I need to start ? Only a DC motor driver or anything else?

Thanks in advance
LStrike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need:

- Emergency switch (it should be easy to cut the power off, even for small robots)
- A chassis (you've found one already)
- Motors (Obviously)
- Motor control (Probably a dual H-bridge, think if you need reverse or not.)
- Power (powering on (single use) batteries may not be your best option)
- Controller (Arduino Uno, or something smaller or faster)
- Sensors (Can be anything, depending on the requirements)

A way to communicate with the robot is also nice, often wireless (bluetooth/wifi/443mhz).

And also, it will be nice if the robot fits some kind of purpose, but this could be added later.
You could think of the robot having to pick up and carry something, extinguish a flame etc.

I advise to check out one of the many tutorials on building a robot, they often have a detailed parts list (sometimes even shopping links).

Comment: Thats a nice list, thx. Never thought about an Emergency switch. I think I will start small with just driving an avoid crashing into objects ;-)

Comment: @LStrike, to avoid crashing into objects, it's often better to use at least 2 sensors that rely on different principles. If you have a "sonar" sensor, and you aim it at a plushy object, at may not work as well. So an extra IR sensor is a nice safety feature. You can check if you need to know the distance to the object, or just registering the object from a set distance is enough.
But yeah, sensors can be added later.